# How to use lists:duplicate?

Tags: erlang

I would like to know if its possible to use lists:duplicate in this case:

```
decompress_1([])->
      [];
decompress_1(L)->
      MyNum = lists:map(fun(T)-> element(1,T) end,L),
      Res = lists:map(fun(T)-> element(2,T) end,L).
```

to get :

```
decompress_1([{3,1},{3,2},{1,5},{1,4},{1,1},{1,0},{1,1}]) == [1,1,1,2,2,2,5,4,1,0,1]
```

I just manage to retrieve the first and second elements of the tuple.
There is a solution with list comprehension but I would know to do it without.

```
decompress([]) ->
     [];
decompress(L) ->
     [Y || {X, Y} <- L, _ <- lists:seq(1, X)].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using a list comprehension, we can use `lists:duplicate/2` to create the result, but we have to flatten it to get the desired final answer:

```
decompress([]) ->
    [];
decompress(L) ->
    lists:flatten(lists:map(fun({X,Y}) ->
                                    lists:duplicate(X,Y)
                            end, L)).
```

Without the `flatten` we'd get the first result shown below, instead of the second correct result:

```
1> decompress_no_flatten([{3,1},{3,2},{1,5},{1,4},{1,1},{1,0},{1,1}]).
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[5],[4],[1],[0],[1]]
2> decompress([{3,1},{3,2},{1,5},{1,4},{1,1},{1,0},{1,1}]).
[1,1,1,2,2,2,5,4,1,0,1]
```

By the way, you can use `lists:duplicate/2` in the original list comprehension approach as well:

```
decompress([]) ->
    [];
decompress(L) ->
    [Y || {X,Y} <- L, _ <- lists:duplicate(X,Y)].
```

This works because here we don't use the values produced by `lists:seq/2` or `lists:duplicate/2`, but rather we use only the number of items they produce.

Comment: Instead of flattening the result of a map you could use `lists:flatmap`.